# What is a common general term to refer to a man with large strong muscle?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

**What is a common general term to refer to a man with large strong muscle?**

For example, "**he is very muscly**" or "**he is well-built**".

He may or may not go to the gym. Maybe, he was born that way.

Comment: Adjectives - built, ripped, in shape, musclebound.

Comment: Many more terms have an additional implication... of attractiveness (hunk, beefcake), sport (jock, athletic-build), disposition/intelligence (himbo, meathead, bruiser), and overall size (giant, absolute unit, thick).

Comment: "Built like a brick shithouse" is my dad's favourite :)

Comment: My favorite is "chiseled" (as in from stone, like a statue).

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to such a man as husky, burly, thickset, beefy, brawny.

The online dictionary is a useful source to find good synonyms, with clickable links to their meanings. See [the definition of muscular](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/muscular)

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].